# Client side entity proxies inheritance in GWT Requestfactoy

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

I use GWT 2.5 RequestFactory,
Suppose at server side, I have `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` 4 entities, at client side, i have `AProxy`, `BProxy`,`CProxy`, `DProxy` corresponding to server side entities.
`B`, `C` extends `A`. In `D` entity, i have a method:

```
A getEntity();
```

which will **actually** return `B` or `C`,
At client side, in `DProxy`, i have:

```
AProxy getEntity();
```

My question is At client side, when i get `AProxy`, can i cast it to `BProxy` or `CProxy`, If not, is there a way to get the **actual** entity proxy?

P.S. In DProxy, i have `@ExtraTypes({BProxy,CProxy})`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `BPRoxy extends AProxy` with `@ProxyFor(B.class)` (or equivalent) and `CProxy extends AProxy` with `@ProxyFor(C.class)` (or equivalent), then yes, it should work: `getEntity()` will return either an `AProxy`, `BProxy` or `CProxy` depending on the object returned on the server-side.